# Why am I getting a "softfail" for my SPF check?

Tags: spf

I don't know how to setup my DNS TXT record correctly. I keep getting an "softfail"

```
Result:         softfail (SPF-Result: SoftFail)
ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=alex@alexecollins.com
 DNS record(s):
   alexecollins.com. SPF (no records)
   alexecollins.com. 360 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ptr a:mail.alexecollins.com ~all"
   alexecollins.com. 3600 IN A 188.166.131.249
   alexecollins.com. 14400 IN MX 10 mail.alexecollins.com.
   mail.alexecollins.com. 3600 IN A 188.166.131.249
   247.2.85.95.in-addr.arpa. 1800 IN PTR alexecollins.com.
   alexecollins.com. 3600 IN A 188.166.131.249
   mail.alexecollins.com. 3600 IN A 188.166.131.249
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell from what you've provided; it's missing the IP of where you're testing this from.

In general, it will be giving a softfail because your source IP does not match any of the IPs for your `a`, `mx` and `mail.alexecollins.com` records, and so is falling back to your `~all` softfail default action.

The solution will be to add a clause to your SPF record that *does* cover where you're sending from.

Comment: Is this a case of adding the ip4 to the record?

Comment: Yes, or some other type that resolves to the same address.